# Parallax effect jitter in libGDX

Tags: camera, libgdx, parallax, smoothing, jitter

Basically I'm using [this ParallaxCamera class](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/ParallaxTest.java) to create the effect in my game, but upon movement, the layers "wiggle". This is especially noticeable when the camera is moving slowly.

I have fixed the timestep and use interpolated smoothing. I use scaled up pixel art. Camera centered on player, updated after movement. Disabling the effect makes moving the camera smooth.

What I guess the issues might be:

- the layers move at different paces which means they move at different
  times
- rounding to display makes the layers assume slightly different positions each frame when moving the camera

Thanks for any help

Comment: Is your game low-res pixel art? Are you using nearest filtering on your textures?

Comment: yeah, I have 384x216 with nearest and I scale it. when scaled, it correctly uses the extra resolution for animation however, the layers just don't move together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For low-resolution pixel art, this is the strategy I've used. I draw to a small FrameBuffer at 1:1 resolution and then draw that to the screen. That should take care of jittering.

If your Stage is also at the same resolution, then you have to use a bit of a hack to get input to be processed properly. The one I've used it to use a StretchViewport, but I manually calculate the world width and height to not stretch the world, so I'm basically doing the same calculation that ExtendViewport does behind the scenes. You also have to round to an integer for the width and height. You should do this in `resize` and apply the width and height using `viewport.setWorldWidth()` and `setWorldHeight()`. So in this case it doesn't matter what world size you give to the constructor since it will be changed in `update()`.

When you call `update` on the viewport in `resize`, you need to do it within the context of the FrameBuffer you are drawing to. Otherwise it will mess up the screen's frame buffer dimensions.

```java
public void resize(int width, int height) {

    int worldWidth = Math.round((float)WORLD_HEIGHT / (float)height * (float)width);
    viewport.setWorldWidth(worldWidth);
    viewport.setWorldHeight(worldHeight);
    frameBuffer.begin();
    viewport.update(width, height, true); // the actual screen dimensions
    frameBuffer.end();

}
```

You can look up examples of using FrameBuffer in LibGDX. You should do all your game drawing in between `frameBuffer.begin()` and `end()`, and then draw the frameBuffer's color buffer to the screen like this:

```java
stage.act();
frameBuffer.begin();
//Draw game
stage.draw();
frameBuffer.end();
spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(spriteBatch.getProjectionMatrix().idt());
spriteBatch.begin();
spriteBatch.draw(frameBuffer.getColorBufferTexture(), -1, 1, 2, -2);
spriteBatch.end();
```

In my case, I do a more complicated calculation of world width and world height such that they are a whole number factor of the actual screen dimensions. This prevents the big pixels from being different sizes on the screen, which might look bad. Alternatively, you can change the filtering of the FrameBuffer's texture to linear and use an upscaling shader when drawing it.

Comment: framebuffer didn't do much but I guess it won't hurt. I made a little video where it's clearly visible(cloud vs mountain vs forest vs foreground) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eA3eMqwhNZM no scaling issues with screenviewport, actually lets me use any resolution. game is slowed x28 for video. if I look closely I can see this even in games like terraria but lots of tiny movements exacerbate it. makes me think the nature of parallax is responsible, perhaps it gets less and less bad the higher the scaling(eg on 4k display). you only use stage for ui right? thanks for the help

Comment: FrameBuffer would make this type of jitter impossible because the pixels could not move a fractional distance. In your video I can see that you're not using a FrameBuffer with 1:1 pixel art scale because the pixels of different layers are able to partially overlap each other.

Comment: well if my layers only moved in exact pixels, it would be even more jittery wouldn't it? or what exactly is the purpose of framebuffer here? I used your code, only with screenviewport because that gave me perfect scaling to any resolution

Comment: It will move more "blocky" instead of jittery. It will be no different than an actual retro game, where you never had pixels partially overlapping each other. The "blocky" effect is not nausea-inducing like the jittering is. I do it this way to achieve an authentic retro look. This strategy will not work if that's not the appearance you want.

Comment: I haven't gone for that look before. I think the solution might be a custom shader where you make the textures linear, and then in the shader apply a function to the texture coords before using them such that they do mostly-nearest filtering except at a narrow region at the edges of texels. This would be to give it a tiny amount of smoothness at the very edges of your pixels. You would make this smooth region about the width of a resultant screen pixel. I haven't done any of this before...it's just an idea.

Comment: well it's very wobbly for me. unity games like hollow knight have very good parallax so there must be something

Comment: Hollow Knight has high-resolution sprites with linear filtering. The jittering is the result of nearest filtering rounding. That's why I suggest the shader solution to use linear filtering while preserving a low-resolution appearance. But for an example of the kind of thing I did in the answer above, look at Shovel Knight. That's also in Unity, and they use the same perspective camera setup as Hollow Knight does, but they must be rendering to a small frame buffer like in my example above, because the pixels never partially overlap each other.

Comment: uhh maybe I should stick to top down games then XD or get better at drawing .. shovel knight doesn't overlap? what do you mean? it doesn't look like it moves in whole pixels to me.. doesn't shovel knight work better because it's x axis only, there are few layers and the character moves at a constant speed? the frame buffer thing didn't really work for me, what exactly am I supposed to see? just the same thing as I would with no scaling except bigger right? or am I missing something here? and whoa, setting the filter to linear and all jitter is gone ...